# How to invest bitcoins?

Tags: investing, loans

Are there any websites where bitcoin holders can invest their money? Such as by buying shares or giving out loans. For example there is a [ShareHolder](https://www.shareholder.ru/About.aspx) service for WebMoney. Is there something similar for Bitcoin?

Comment: A great answer to this question would be a link to a website that actively maintain a list of such websites, otherwise the answer here will likely get out of date.

Comment: When a venture raises capital in bitcoins it spends those on assets and contracts tied to fiat money.  As a result if the exchange rate rises, the venture's earnings are at a lower rate (in terms of bitcoins).  As a result, the lower dividends cause the valuation for the venture to drop.  So it is very difficult for a business to either be capitalized using bitcoins without the investor losing if the exchange rate rises.  Simply holding bitcoins as an asset has provided better returns than "putting the funds to work" has returned.

Answer (score 7):

A list of Bitcoin-related financial investment services:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Financial

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Beware, making use of the following could be dangerous, risky, or even illegal:

- http://btcjam.com p2p loans
- http://polimedia.us/mpex stock exchange and options contracts
- https://coinbr.com an mpex broker (makes it easier to use mpex)
- https://icbit.se futures, mostly
- https://cryptostocks.com stock exchange

Comment: The "dangerous and risky" label is accurate, but "illegal" remains to be seen. European Central Bank considers bitcoin market to be existing outside its regulation (only normal trade laws apply), US/UK authorities did not issue clear assessment yet afaik. But it's reasonable to assume there isn't bigger legal threat, than for example, accessing unlicensed online casinos.

Comment: I did leave a little wiggle room in that statement just for that concern, essentially saying that it 'could be illegal'

Comment: I have been using btcjam and it is pretty simple. However people aren't really offering competitive rates, the highest reasonable return i have seen is 5%. There are higher ones, but only for untrustworthy people.

Comment: @PeterMichealLacey-Bordeaux, it may have improved since your comment. I've successfully invested in several high interest ones. You should do due diligence as with  anything and don't only go by the ratings the site shows. Also look at number of trades and even ask the borrower to chat offline and send more verification if you have doubts of their ability or motivations to repay.

Answer (score 0):

A new exchange just opened at http://btct.co operated by the same person running http://litecoinglobal.com

Answer (score 0):

I've had some pretty good luck with Cryptostocks.com. Not all of the things on that site are things I would condone. There's a lot of stock for groups that do orchestrated pump and dumps. But they also have miners and companies that are building economies for cryptocurrencies, which I approve of. It takes all kinds, I guess.

Answer (score -2):

You could invest IN bitcoins or you could invest your bitcoins.. Slight difference. There are several companies that offer cash gold silver etc investments that now allow you to invest your bitcoins too. Google finds few results as yet but they are out there. I use a non-profit investment company at www.bitcointrustgroup.org as they seem to offer good returns but on the downside they only offer long term investments if you dont want to suffer penalties for early withdrawal.

Comment: -1 never trust someone who wants to anonymously hold your money